# Как использовать имя сущности с переменной в XSL?

Tags: xslt

Есть сущности, например:

```
<!ENTITY object_1  "значение 1">
<!ENTITY object_test  "значение 3">
<!ENTITY object_test2  "значение 5">
```

Определяю сущность:

```
&object_test;
```

Все ок выводит: "значение 3"

Вопрос как можно определять сущность с переменной? Например:

```
&object_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ;
```

Пробовал что-то вроде:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;object_', ../@name, ';')" />
```

выводит: просто имя сущности `"&object_test;"`

Все подобные манипуляции привели меня к одному и тому же результату.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам подойдёт следующий вариант.
Вынесем все сущности, которые нужно использовать и в xml-документе, и в xsl-трансформации в отдельный файл entities.dtd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!ENTITY object_1     "значение 1">
<!ENTITY object_test  "значение 3">
<!ENTITY object_test2 "значение 5">
```

Далее подключим его и там, и там.
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "entities.dtd">
<root>
    <a>&object_1;</a>
    <b>&object_test;</b>
    <c>&object_test2;</c>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet SYSTEM "entities.dtd">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:value-of select="'&object_1;'"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

То есть сущности теперь можно использовать и там, и там.

---

Если необходимо получать имя используемой сущности в ходе выполнения трансформации, то на ум приходит условие:

```
<xsl:if test="../@name = 'test'">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&object_test;'"/>
</xsl:if>
```